# How to catch an event of a file being dragged & dropped from desktop to QWebView in a Qt (PyQt) application with javascript

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtwebkit, qwebview

I am working on an application in PyQt. I made the UI with QWebView which gets loaded with an HTML page.

This HTML page contains a javascript code which detects if a file was dropped on a certain DIV.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');


        $('.input').bind('drop', function(e) {
            var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
            alert(files[0].name);
        });
    });
```

This works fine if I load the HTML code in Chrome.

If I run my application and D&D a file in QWebView that javascript code doesn't get executed.

I extended the QWebView and added the events so I can catch the D&D event with python.

```py
class BrowserWindow(QtWebKit.QWebView):
def __init__(self, parent):
    super(BrowserWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setAcceptDrops(True)

def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()

def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
        event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()

def dropEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
        event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
        event.accept()
        urls = event.mimeData().urls()
        print str(urls[0].toLocalFile())
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

Is there an option to catch such event directly with javascript in QWebView?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to say without bothering to implement the D&D events and make javascript catch it directly, then *no*. Because QWebView has to accept the D&D and then signal javascript about any such event. The reason why the D&D works on chrome by just implementing the JS is that chrome has enabled and implemented the D&D event which are then signaled over to JS.

It's analogous to setting the `viewport` of any QtGui element to `acceptDrop` or else the D&D event of the element will not be triggered.

Comment: I would be happy to continue with the python code for catching events, but right now the only solution that I have in my head is that I catch D&D event with python and then somehow get X and Y position of mouse cursor. Then pass X, Y and filename to javascript like this: `self.mainThread.view.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(code)` I don't believe that this is the right approach.